# jqGrid inline edit: odd behavior with an autocomplete column

Tags: jqgrid, autocomplete

I have a jqGrid (using inline editing) with an autocomplete column.  When the user selects a value from the autocomplete column, an event handler sets a value on another column, and also sets the value on the autocomplete column to something other than the `label` returned from the autocomplete source.  The two column definitions (complete [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/syltech/27dLM/37/) example here):

```
{
    name: 'cartoonId',
    index: 'cartoonId',
    width: 90,
    editable: false},
{
    name: 'cartoon',
    index: 'cartoon',
    width: 200,
    editable: true,
    edittype: 'text',
    editoptions: {
        dataInit: function(elem) {
            $(elem).autocomplete({
                source: autocompleteSource,
                select: function(event, ui){
                    var rowId = $("#inlineGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                    if(ui.item){
                        $("#inlineGrid").jqGrid('setCell', rowId, 'cartoonId', ui.item.CartoonId);
                        $("#inlineGrid").jqGrid('setCell', rowId, 'cartoon', ui.item.Name);                            
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }},
```

The problem is that whenever the user selects a value from the autocomplete, either by clicking it or using arrows and pressing the tab key, that cell is no longer editable, and the grid appears to lose focus entirely.  If I comment out the line that sets the `cartoon` cell value, it behaves normally.  Is there any way I can get around this behavior?  I need the entire row to remain in edit mode, including the `cartoon` column, until the user completes the edit.

jqGrid 4.4.1
jQuery 1.7.2
jQuery UI 1.8.18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rename `Name` property of the items from the `autocompleteSource` to `value` because jQuery UI Autocomplete examines the `label` and `value` per default (see [the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#overview)).

You can't use `setCell` of the `'cartoon'` column which is currently in the editing mode. You should remove `return false;` from `select` callback too. So the code could looks about the following

```js
dataInit: function (elem) {
    $(elem).autocomplete({
        source: autocompleteSource,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var rowId = $("#inlineGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            if (ui.item) {
                $("#inlineGrid").jqGrid('setCell', rowId, 'cartoonId',
                    ui.item.CartoonId);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/27dLM/38/

Comment: You saved me again, Oleg.  Thanks!!